# Occupancy rate for a row of houses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, finance

Consider a row of houses. Define the occupancy rate to be the fraction of days occupied to days available. Suppose that the median occupancy rate for the houses is defined by $x$. The median rent for the houses per month is $\$77.91$.

If the median occupancy rate increased by $5$%, what would be the profit made?

**My attempt:**

If the occupancy rate increases by $5$%, then the new occupancy rate is given by $0.05x$. The rent per month is $\$77.91$, so the total amount made in a month is $0.05x\times\$77.91$. Hence, the increase in the amount made (the profit) by the landlord is $0.05x\times 77.91-\left(5\%\times\$77.91\right)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You start your attempt a little bit wrong. If $x$ increase by $5~\%$, the new value is not $0.05x$ but rather $1.05x$. Intuition behind this: $0.05x$ is much smaller than $x$, in fact it is equal to $1/20$ of $x$. So definitely $0.05x$ doesn't mean "increased by 5 per cent".

Comment: But your expression is almost correct. Before the increase, the income is 
$$
77.91 \cdot (x)
$$ 
And after the increase, it's
$$
77.91\cdot (1.05x)
$$
Now, you must merely take their difference ...

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for your response. Does $77.91\cdot(1.05x)-77.91\cdot (x)$ represent the increase in profit for a single house for a month? So if there are $15$ houses, we can multiply this value by $15$.

Comment: Yes, I would interpret it so.